# Replace chars like replaceAll(string, start, end, '_', '-')

Tags: c++, stl, replace

I want to replace the string `text=s_o_m_e=text` with `text=s-o-m-e=text`

I have a starting and ending index:

```
std::string str("text=s_o_m_e=text");

std::string::size_type start = str.find("text="), end;

if (start != std::string::npos) {
    end = str.find("=", start);

    if (end != std::string::npos) {
        //...
    }
}
```

So, I'm looking for a function like this:

```
replaceAll(string, start, end, '_', '-');
```

UP:

```
std::replace(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, '_', '-');
```

Thanks, [Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a function in `<algorithm>` for that.

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '_', '-');
```

Comment: More thx! So, my solution: `std::replace(str.begin() + start, str.end() + end, '_', '-');`

Comment: @Duglas: You don't want to reference past the end of the string. Because you are using offsets, I think you want `std::replace(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, '_', '-');`

Comment: There is a huge limitation of using std::replace, the old_string and new_string must have the same length. i.e. std::replace(my_str.begin(), my_str.end(), "old string", "can't touch this"); will fail at template argument deduction i.e. "template argument deduction/substitution failed; note:  deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘char [11]’ and ‘char [17]’)"

Comment: @BadDesign: It's not so much a limitation as a misuse of the algorithm. Your example wouldn't work even if the string literals were the same length. `std::string` is a container of `char` elements and those string literals can't be converted from `const char *` to `char`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Right. Is there anything in the C++ Standard Library that does what I did in my example? (Something like you can do with boost::algorithm::replace_all(my_str, "test", "qwertyuiop"))

Comment: @BadDesign: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a simple Standard Library replacement for that Boost function. You'd probably have to do it the hard way using [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), and [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::replace`. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) is more details.

Comment: -1, Bad answer: a little snippet to show how to use it would make it much better.

Comment: -1. Even the link referenced in this answer doesn't provide enough information