# C++ string replace doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, string, replace

small question about C++ replace function. I'm parsing every line of text input line by line. Example of the text file:

```
SF27_34KJ
EEE_30888
KPD324222
4230_333
```

And I need to remove all the underscores on every line and replace it with a comma. When I try something like this:

> mystring.replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), '_', ',');

on every line - instead of "**SF27,34KJ**" I get 95x "**,**" char. What could be wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string

Comment: You are confusing `std::replace` with `string.replace`.

Comment: Short explanation: `std::replace` replaces all occurrences of a string within another, whereas `string::replace` just replaces a substring in a specified location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
std::replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), '_', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

`basic_string::replace` doesn't do what you think it does.

`basic_string::replace(it_a, it_e, ... )` replaces *all* of the characters between `it_a` and `it_e` with whatever you specify, not just those that match something.

There are a hundred ways to do what you're trying to do, but the simplest is probably to use the `std::replace` from `<algorithm>`, which *does* do what you want:

```
std::replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), '_', ',');
```

Another method is to use `std::transform` in conjunction with a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).  This has an advantage over `std::replace` in that you can perform multiple substitutions in a single pass.

Here is a C++03 functor that would do it:

```
struct ReplChars
{
    char operator()(char c) const
    {
        if( c == '_' )
            return ',';
        if( c == '*' )
            return '.';
        return c;
    }
};
```

...and the use of it:

```
std::transform(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), mystring.begin(), ReplChars());
```

In C++11, this can be reduced by using a lambda instead of the functor:

```
std::transform(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), mystring.begin(), [](char c)->char
{
    if( c == '_' )
        return ',';
    if( c == '*' )
        return '.';
    return c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/), there is no replace method which takes two iterators and then two characters.  Considering the ascii value of '_' is 95, I'm guessing you're hitting this one instead:

```
string& replace ( iterator i1, iterator i2, size_t n2, char c );
```

So instead of replacing all instances of '_' with ',', instead you're replacing the string from `begin()` to `end()` with 95 ','s.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string) for how to replace occurrances in a string.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly how replace works. Check out the api http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/, you give iterators for the beginning and end along with a string to copy in, but the other argument is the maximum length of that section.

To get the functionality that you're going for, try finding a substring and replacing it (two calls). That's detailed here: [Replace part of a string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/c-replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string) .