# Replacing all instances of one ascii character with another in c++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

E.g, I have a string, "Hello World" and I want to replace all the "l"s with "1"s. How would I do this? I am new to c++. Most of my background is in Python in which you could just use the .replace method.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::replace`.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    std::replace(str.begin(),str.end(),'l','1');
    std::cout << str; //He11o Wor1d
}
```