# Replace one array of a string in .net

Tags: c++, .net, string

So I'm trying to change one array of a string because I need to replace a dot (.) into a comma (,)

Here's what I've tried :

```
if(this->textBox1->Text[1]='.')
             {
                 this->textBox1->Text[1]=',';
             }
```

But that doesn't work as expected.

Is the problem coming from the fact I'm trying to change from the textbox ?

Comment: `=` Is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator. `if(this->textBox1->Text[1]=='.')`

Comment: clarify why you are tagging .net, are you using CLI c++?

Comment: You want to replace one character of a string. The string does not contain arrays.

Comment: If you want to replace all dots you can use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2896627