# How to replace an occurrence of whitespace in a string with an underscore using c++?

Tags: c++

How can I replace each occurrence (in a string) of whitespace with an underscore?

I may only use the following standard headers:

- `<iostream>`
- `<string>`
- `<cctype>`

Comment: You didn't use the post preview. :( Have you considered searching for existing questions and research material on replacing characters with other characters in a string?

Comment: This would be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2896600/560648 if it weren't for what seems like an entirely arbitrary restriction on what headers you may use. Homework? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it's not quite the same. The linked question only replaces a single character, while this question asks about any sort of whitespace, which could include space, tab, newline, and maybe some more.

Comment: Is it one underscore per whitespace character, or per block of contiguous whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

The brute force method:

```
std::string text = "Is the economy getting worse?";
const unsigned int length = text.length();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
  if (text[i] == ' ')
  {
    text[i] = '_';
  }
}
```

Only the header `<string>` is required.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious method seems to be:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<s.size(); i++) 
    if (isspace((unsigned char)s[i])) 
        s[i] = '_';
```

Note a couple of points:

1. You want to use `isspace`, not compare directly to the space character. If you do, you'll miss things like tabs.
2. You want to cast the character to `unsigned char` before passing to `isspace`. Otherwise it can (and often will) have problems with characters outside the basic ASCII character set (e.g., letters with accents/umlauts).

Answer (score -1):

There's no single C++ string method to do this - you'll need a loop:

```
// C++ replace all
#include <cctype.h>
...
string string replaceChar(string str, char new_char) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if (isspace((unsigned char)str[i]))
      str[i] = new_char;
  }
  return str;
}
```

If you happened to have a null terminated C string, you could do this:

```
/* C replace all */
#include <ctype.h>
...
char *replaceChar (char *str, char new_char) {
    char *p = str;
    unsigned char c;
    while (c = *p) {
      if (isspace(c))
        *p = new_char;
      p++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

ADDENDUM: generalized solution to use "isspace()": replaces *all* "whitespace" characters.

Comment: Also this only replaces one character, rather than all whitespace

Comment: @Mooing Duck - std::string::replace doesn't "replace all", does it"?

Comment: `std::string::replace` replaces the next, and can trivially be used in a two-line loop to replace all.  Or, `std::replace` will also do a replace all.  Your pick.