# C++ Code not displaying the output in the same line

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[10] = "Anmol" ;
    int age = 17 ;
    cout << "Enter your name here :- " ;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) ;
    cout << "Enter your age here :- " ;
    cin >> age ;
    cout << "Hello World, It's " << str << "And my age is " << age ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

On running the code, the compiler is giving output in different line like:-
[image: How the program is working on execution]

Comment: I think that fgets is catching the enter that you use to send age, verify it.

Comment: `fgets` leaves a newline in the string.  Use getline.

Comment: After reading using `fgets()`, checking `str[strlen(str)-1]` will contain a `'\n'` i.e. a newline character (unless the user enters a name with more than 9 characters).   That's how `fgets()` works.

Answer (score 2):

fgets() is a file function which is used to read text from keyboard, as in “file get string.”
fgets() function is read the string as well as "enter" character ascii code which is 13 (carriage return - CR) .so the above code consider the CR character at the end of the 'str' that's why it print in the next line .

You can use the gets_s() function to take the string from the keyboard.
Try the below code .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[10] = "Anmol";
    int age = 17;
    cout << "Enter your name here :- ";
    gets_s(str);
    cout << "Enter your age here :- ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Hello World, It's " << str << " And my age is " << age;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: You can see the output in attached screenshort]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaKKr.png

Answer (score 1):

try replace '\r\n', and '\n\r' with '' in str

look at here for replace in string :  [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

Comment: Given that OP is using [XTerm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/), I doubt they have Windows newlines. However, all newlines will simply be read as a C++ `\n` character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int age;
    cout << "Enter your name here :- " ;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Enter your age here :- " ;
    cin >> age ;
    cout << "Hello World, It's " << str 
         << " And my age is " << age << endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `fgets()`, you also get the ending newline character in the input. That explains your output. You could use `std::getline` to avoid that problem.

---

```
int main()
{
   std::string str = "Anmol" ;
   int age = 17 ;
   cout << "Enter your name here :- " ;
   std::getline((std::cin, str) ;
   cout << "Enter your age here :- " ;
   cin >> age ;
   cout << "Hello World, It's " << str << " and my age is " << age << std::endl;
   return 0 ;
}
```