# How to replace "\" with "\\" in c++ String

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have `string My_string = "First string\r\nSecond string\r\nThird string"` ... ect.
New string starts after \r\n and I want to replace `\` with `\\`.

I have tried with:-
`My_string.replace("\","\\");` But it doesn't work for me.
Is there any another way to do it?

Comment: Is it C or C++? There is no string type in C.

Comment: There is no thing such as `"\"` in C or C++. It gives you the start of an escape sequence. So it isn't really clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: One reason for problems is because there are *no* backslashes in the string. If you have a string literal then the compiler will replace escape sequences (like `"\r\n"`) with their actual encoded values (using [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) the example of `"\r\n"` will be replaced by the two bytes `13` and `10` inside the string).

Comment: look at the syntax highlighting, don't you see anything suspicious?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. @stack_: If you can update the question with valid code and be more clear about what you want, then please do so.

Comment: It is for c++11 string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert escape characters (\n, \r, etc.) to a literal backslash and the [a-z] character, you can use a switch statement and append to a buffer. Assuming a C++ standard library string, you may do:

```
std::string escaped(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;
    output.reserve(input.size());
    for (const char c: input) {
        switch (c) {
            case '\a':  output += "\\a";        break;
            case '\b':  output += "\\b";        break;
            case '\f':  output += "\\f";        break;
            case '\n':  output += "\\n";        break;
            case '\r':  output += "\\r";        break;
            case '\t':  output += "\\t";        break;
            case '\v':  output += "\\v";        break;
            default:    output += c;            break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

This uses a switch statement, and converts all common escape sequences to a literal '\' and the character used to represent the escape sequence. All other characters are appended as-is to the string. Simple, efficient, easy-to-use.

Comment: Thank You so much !!!!! It works for me:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code?

```
My_string.replace( My_string.begin(), My_string.end(), 'x', 'y'); //replace all occurances of 'x' with 'y'
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string) is a similar question