# Ouputting String Literal from a variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know if it is possible to output a raw string from a preset variable whose value I cannot change. For example:

```
string test = "test\ntest2";
cout << test;
```

would output

```
test
test2
```

Is it possible to run similar code as above but change the cout statement to print the raw string like so:

```
test\ntest2
```

Comment: How about basic escaping `"test\\ntest2"`?

Comment: The variable is set, I cannot change it, as stated in my question.

Comment: I see. The last paragraph was misleading because it implied that you could change the literal. (But I edited mainly so that I could retract my vote...)

Comment: Are you trying to get _the original_ representation, or just _an unambiguous_ representation?

Comment: The brute force way would be to replace every occurrence of `"\n"` with `"\\n"` in your string (and then repeat for all the other escape sequences).  See the SO question [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2896600/654614) for code.

Comment: `qDebug()` from the Qt library does something like that. Perhaps take a look at how that it implemented (it's open source).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An escape sequence `\x` is translated into only **one** character.

There are probably some platforms out there for which an endline character is printed as `\n` but this is solely implementation dependent.

Translating this then to **two** characters (`\` and `x`), would mean you would have to modify the `string` itself.

The easiest way of doing that is making a custom function.

```
void print_all(std::string s)
{
    for (char c : s) {
        switch (c) {
            case '\n' : std::cout << "\\n"; break;
            case '\t' : std::cout << "\\t"; break;

            // etc.. etc..

            default : std::cout << c;
        }
    }
}
```

For all [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) you care about.

Note: unlike `ctrl-x` and `x`, there is no direct correlation between the values of `\x` and `x`, *at least in the ASCII table*, so a `switch` statement is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use raw string literals if you have c++11.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << R"(test\ntest2)" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Mike

Comment: I had it originally in my post, but it seems it was edited out, but I cannot access the string stored in the variable at all, I have to use the variable declaration