# Repeated Function call in the following program in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to write a programs that takes an input of string which has some '$' and digits. The output of the program is set of all possible strings where the '$ in the string is replaced by all the other digits.
I have written the following code for it.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int numberOf(string in)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= in.size()-1; i++)
        if(in[i] == '$')
            count++;

    return count;
}
void solve(string in, string in1, vector <string> &s,
    int index)
{

    if(numberOf(in) == 0)
    {
        s.push_back(in);
        return;
    }

    if(index == in.size())
    {
        return;
    }

    if(in1.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    
    else
    {
        if(in[index] == '$')
        {
            string in2 = in;
            in2[index] = in1[0];
            string in3 = in1;
            in3.erase(in3.begin());
            solve(in2, in1, s, index+1);
            solve(in, in3, s, index);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            solve(in, in1, s, index+1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void replaceDollar(string in)
{
    string in1 = in;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= in.size()- 1; i++)
    {
        if(in[i] != '$')
        {
            in1.push_back(in[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
    count = in.size() - count;
    cout << "Number is " << count << "\n";

    vector <string> s;
    solve(in, in1, s, 0);

    for(auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << " ";
    cout << "\n";

}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string in;
        cin >> in;
        replaceDollar(in);
    }
return 0;
}
```

For following input

```
1
$45
```

The expected output should be

```
445 545
```

But it returns

```
445 545 445 545
```

Can anyone please explain why is it outputting repeated strings?
Also can anyone suggest a better approach to this question?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to start your program in a debugger and step line by line through your code? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What output do you expect for `1 $$45`? Is it just `4445 5545` or `4445 4545 5445 5545`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Not as of now, I use a simple text editor

Comment: @brc-dd `4445 4545 5445 5545`

Comment: Then you should start using a debugger. It will show you the problem.

Comment: @alphaRomeoNovember This [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-the-string-by-replacing-with-any-other-digit-from-the-string/) may help you. Although, I don't recommend this site, but in its comment section you can find some good implementation using STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is homework:

1. Start over. Your code is way too complex for this problem.
2. I would treat everything as type `char`
3. Loop/iterate over said string, using `std::string::replace()` to replace each instance of `$` with each digit.
   -- If your teacher doesn't want you using `std` libraries, then add another loop and compare yourself.
   3a. Of course, add a check, so that you don't replace `$` with `$`
4. Create a new copy of the string on each iteration.
5. Print each to `stdout` as you create them.

See this post:

[How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

p.s. Pro tip: don't use `using namespace`. Use the full namespace in your calls; e.g.:

**Bad**

```
using namespace std;
string = "hello world";
```

**Good**

```
std::string = "hello world";
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. I know the solution is complex but I was trying to implement it using recursion. Anything to refine the recursion ?

Comment: With recursion I find it best to first clearly define the exit strategy: in your case, a ``$`` char (or ``\0``). Now iterate over each digit in the given string, and strip off chars 1 by 1 until you hit the exit condition. Eg: 534$6:  (5 + (3 + (4 + (exit, return replace + rest of string)))), roughly pseudocoded: replacer(str[0] + replacer(str[1..end]) ...  until str[0] is "$" ... exit, return rest of string, and build final string as you unwind.

Comment: Be concise. The recursive routine should be about five lines of code. Check for the exit condition; if not met, recurse again, passing the string with first char removed. In programming, less is more :)

Comment: Thanks kmiklas, thats what I was looking for! I shall soon implement it and update the post.