# Why should I use string.erase()?

Tags: c++, string

I need to replace the whitespaces " " in a string with `@40` and have to do in O(1) space complexity. I cannot create a temp string or use auxiliary memory.

```
Input: Hello I love coding Coding Ninjas India

Output:Hello@40I@40love@40coding@40Coding@40Ninjas@40India
```

This is my current code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string replaceSpaces(string &str)
{
    int i=0;
    string temp="";
     while(i < str.length())
    {
        if(str[i] ==' ')
        {
           str.erase(i,1);
           str.insert(i,"@40");
        }
        i++;
    } 
    return str;
}  
int main()
{
   string s="Hello I love coding Coding Ninjas India";
   cout << "Ans--> " << replaceSpaces(s) << endl;
}
```

When I am not writing str.erase() and directly inserting `@40` my code is not running, so I do not understand why we have to use str.erase(i,1) and string by 1 before inserting.

Comment: if you don't erase the space it will be shifted to position `i+3` where you find it again, then again you prepend `"@40"` and shift the space by 3, and find it again 3 iterations later, and so on... you should use a debugger to see what happens

Comment: _"...in O(1) space complexity no temp string can be used..."_ `str.insert(i,"@40");` this will internally copy the string buffer as the code adds more characters than it removes.  This copy can potentially happen multiple times so `O(1)` will not be achieved.

Comment: _"no temp string can be used"_  Consider removing `string temp` then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing even digits in string with given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343501/replacing-even-digits-in-string-with-given-string)

Comment: See also [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace)

Comment: Doing the described task in `O(1)` requires violating several fundamental rules of physics of our shared universe. This is not going to be easy.

Comment: The size of the output string may be 3x as large as the input string which makes it impossible to store the output string, using `O(1)` memory, even if you reuse the input string; the best you can do is to change the function signature to `std::string replaceSpaces(std::string)`, count the number of spaces, call `resize` on the string passed as param and iterate backwards replacing content.You could print the desired output using `O(1)` memory of course by simply iterating through the string char by char and printing the char or `"@40"`, depending on whether you encounter a space char or not.

Comment: This feels like a badly worded question either from a college/university class or some coding website. The only reasonable way: scan first, count the spaces. Perform **one** allocation with the extra spaces times two. Scan the string backwards pushing the existing characters forwards, replacing the spaces with `"@40"`

Comment: Alternatively, just use `std::string::replace` and only care about performance/complexity when it gets to show in a profile. FTW.